# "Point in polygon" counts that respond to filters?

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, dynamic

I have a list of addresses in one layer and a polygon layer of census block groups for the local town, all stored in postgis.  I have a nice display right now that labels each polygon with a count of houses within that block group by creating a postgis view along the lines of:

```
create view block_groups_count as
  select g.id, count(1) from
  block_groups g join addresses a
  on st_covers(g.geom, a.geom)
  group by g.id;
```

I can join this with the polygon layer itself and get the labeling I
want.  This works great with respect to modifying the polygon layer: I
can make changes, click "save", and everything updates automatically.

But now that I've got this far, I am looking for a mechanism by which
I can get the labels in the polygon layer to update dynamically in
reaction to changes to qgis filters applied to the address layer.

That is, if I apply a "show only blue houses" filter to the list of
addresses, I want to counts to reflect only the number of blue houses
within in each polygon.

Is it possible to set up this sort of behavior with qgis?

One alternative I've considered is to simply to create a new count
view for each attribute, but this results in several additional
layers, and switching between different views isn't particularly
graceful.